# Why needed PointerTracker and KeyEventHandler class

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, ime, latin

I'm developing in **LatinKeyboard**.
Can anybody please explain what this method does ?

This is a **pointerTracker** class why need PointerTracker class and keyEventHandler Interface in LatinIME.

```
public class PointerTracker { public interface KeyEventHandler { 

    }
```

Thanks for advance